# From Haskell to Python: how to do currying?

Tags: python, function, haskell, currying

I recently started coding in Python and I was wondering if it's possible to return a function that *specializes* another function.

For example, in Haskell you can create a function that adds 5 to any given number like this:

```
sumFive = (+5)
```

Is it somehow possible in Python?

Answer (score 5):

I think the other answers are misunderstanding the question. I believe the OP is asking about partial application of a function, in his example the function is `(+)`.

If the goal isn't partial application, the solution is as simple as:

```
def sumFive(x): return x + 5
```

For partial application in Python, we can use this function: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial

```
def partial(func, *args, **keywords):
    def newfunc(*fargs, **fkeywords):
        newkeywords = keywords.copy()
        newkeywords.update(fkeywords)
        return func(*(args + fargs), **newkeywords)
    newfunc.func = func
    newfunc.args = args
    newfunc.keywords = keywords
    return newfunc
```

Then, we must turn the `+` operator into a function (I don't believe there's a lightweight syntax to do so like in Haskell):

```
def plus(x, y): return x + y
```

Finally:

```
sumFive = partial(plus, 5)
```

Not nearly as nice as in Haskell, but it works:

```
>>> sumFive(7)
12
```

Comment: That `plus` function is already in the standard library: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/operator.html#operator.add

Comment: Partial application is similar to, but distinct from, currying which is what the OP's example shows (I added an answer below showing currying).

Answer (score 3):

Python's design does not naturally support the evaluation of a multi-variable function into a sequence of single-variable functions (*currying*). As other answers point out, the related (but distinct) concept of [*partial application*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying#Contrast_with_partial_function_application) is more straightforward to do using [`partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) from the functools module.

However, the [PyMonad](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyMonad/) library supplies you with the tools to make currying possible in Python, providing a "collection of classes for programming with functors, applicative functors and monads."

Use the `curry` decorator to decorate a function that accepts any number of arguments:

```
from pymonad import curry

@curry
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

It is then very easy to curry `add`. The syntax is not too dissimilar to Haskell's:

```
>>> add5 = add(5)
>>> add5(12)
17
```

Note that here the `add` and `add5` functions are instances of PyMonad's `Reader` monad class, not a normal Python function object:

```
>>> add
<pymonad.Reader.Reader at 0x7f7024ccf908>
```

This allows, for example, the possibility of using simpler syntax to  compose functions (easy to do in Haskell, normally much less so in Python).

Finally, it's worth noting that the infix operator `+` is not a Python function: `+` calls into the left-hand operand's `__add__` method, or the right-hand operand's `__radd__` method and returns the result. You'll need to decorate these class methods for the objects you're working with if you want to curry using `+` (disclaimer: I've not tried to do this yet).

Comment: Good stuff here @ajcr !

Answer (score 2):

Yup.  Python supports lambda expressions:

```
sumFive = lambda x: x + 5

for i in range(5):
   print sumFive(i),

#OUTPUT 5,6,7,8,9
```

Answer (score 1):

Python functions can return functions, allowing you to create higher-order functions. For example, here is a higher-order function which can specialize a function of two variables:

```
def specialize(f,a,i):
    def g(x):
        if i == 0:
            return f(a,x)
        else:
            return f(x,a)
    return g
```

Used like this:

```
>>> def subtract(x,y): return x - y

>>> f = specialize(subtract,5,0)
>>> g = specialize(subtract,5,1)
>>> f(7)
-2
>>> g(7)
2
```

But -- there is really no need to reinvent the wheel, the module [functools](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functools.html) has a number of useful higher-order functions that any Haskell programmer would find useful, including `partial` for partial function application, which is what you are asking about.

Answer (score 1):

As it was pointed out, python does have [lambda functions](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions), so the following does solve the problem:

```
# Haskell: sumFive = (+5)
sumFive = lambda x : x + 5
```

I think this is more useful with the fact that python has first class functions ([1](http://composingprograms.com/pages/16-higher-order-functions.html),[2](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/how-do-you-make-a-higher-order-function-in-python.htm))

```
def summation(n, term):
    total, k = 0, 1
    while k <= n:
        total, k = total + term(k), k + 1
    return total

def identity(x):
    return x

def sum_naturals(n):
    return summation(n, identity)

sum_naturals(10) # Returns 55
# Now for something a bit more complex
def pi_term(x):
    return 8 / ((4*x-3) * (4*x-1))

def pi_sum(n):
    return summation(n, pi_term)

pi_sum(1e6) # returns: 3.141592153589902
```

You can find more on functional programming and python [here](https://newcircle.com/bookshelf/python_fundamentals_tutorial/functional_programming)

Answer (score 0):

For the most generic Haskell style *currying*, look at `partial` from the `functools` module.

Comment: `partial` does partial application, not currying. Currying is turning a function `(a, b) -> t` into a function `a -> b -> t`. Partial application is turning a function `(a, b) -> t` into a function `b -> t` given an `a`.