# Using Classes in Python not initialise all valiables in constructor

Tags: python, class

after looking online there are several ways having a pythonic way for a class definition but not the one I was looking for. I am initialising all variables and both function need all of them. What I want is that not all variables need to be used per function, but only the ones needed, so not all don't need to be initialised:

I have the following test code:

```
class TestClass:

    def __init__(self,a,b,c,d):

        self.a  = a
        self.b  = b
        self.c = c
        self.d = d

    def CalcA(self):

        TestA = self.a + self.b

        return TestA

    def CalcB(self):

        TestB = self.c * self.d

        return TestB

if __name__ == '__main__':

    a=5.0
    b=10.0
    c=2.0
    d =0.01

    TestingTheClass = TestClass(a,b,c,d)
    NewCalcA = TestingTheClass.CalcA()
    NewCalcB = TestingTheClass.CalcB()

    print(NewCalcA)
    print(NewCalcB)
```

Comment: Please clarify: what do you need to do?  You have successfully left `a, b` out of the addition method, and left out `c, d` in the multiplication method.  There are many references on line for optional arguments (default values) in a function, so you should know how to do this for `__init__`.  Where do you have trouble?

Comment: Could you please clarify the problem as currently the code runs and does not have any issues, and your question is not clear on what you are asking.

Comment: @Prune, the code runs well. But what I want to do is, e.g. I only have *a* and *b* and dont want to define *c* and *d* or vice versa. But with my code I have to define all 4 variables. How can I be more flexible giving the function the variables they need?

Comment: @Professor_Joykill, please see my response to Prune.

Comment: @MCM I believe you could you add parameters to the methods and therefore reuse variable names, for example define only a & b, run `CalcA(a,b)` then redefine a & b and run `CalcB(a, b)`

Comment: I still don't understand: your two methods (add & multiply) have only one parameter, `self`.  Since these are methods in a class, they *must* have that one parameter to get invoked.  There is no extra overhead or inefficiency there.  You pass the object handle, nothing else.

Comment: @Professor_Joykill, could you please be more specific changing my example?

Comment: Defining the instance attributes (a, b, c, d) is something you've done in `__init__`; the other methods can't take that away.  If you want `__init__` to be flexible and accept only two arguments (initial values), then look up how to handle optional arguments.

Comment: Is it possible that you're thinking along the lines discussed in this question?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35279806/from-haskell-to-python-how-to-do-currying

Comment: @MCM: No, Joykill cannot change your example -- that is vandalizing the original posting.  However, he can post an answer.

Comment: There is what I was saying, not sure if that's what you meant as your question wasn't entirely clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well this it is hard to figure out what you are asking for here, but i think you might want to check out the usage of default values + passing the parameters as an unpacked dictionary. Like this:

```
class TestClass:

    def __init__(self,a=0,b=0,c=0,d=0):

        self.a  = a
        self.b  = b
        self.c = c
        self.d = d

    def CalcA(self):

        TestA = self.a + self.b

        return TestA

    def CalcB(self):

        TestB = self.c * self.d

        return TestB

if __name__ == '__main__':
    params={"a": 5.0, "b": 10.0}

    TestingTheClass = TestClass(**params)
    NewCalcA = TestingTheClass.CalcA()
    NewCalcB = TestingTheClass.CalcB()
    print(NewCalcA) #15.0
    print(NewCalcB) #0

    params={"c": 2.0, "d":0.01}

    TestingTheClass = TestClass(**params)
    NewCalcA = TestingTheClass.CalcA()
    NewCalcB = TestingTheClass.CalcB()

    print(NewCalcA) #0
    print(NewCalcB) #0.02
```

Now you have your values =0 by default, and you can populate the dict only with the ones that concern you.

Comment: Yes Thanks a lot. I was looking for something like this :).

Answer (score 1):

One possibility to get rid of extra variables(if that is what you are looking for) is to simply use a and b and redefine them so your code in the header of each class will be:

```
def CalcA(self, a, b):

def CalcB(self, c, d):
```

and then your code at the bottom to deal with these would look something like:

```
a=5.0
b=10.0

TestingTheClass = TestClass()
NewCalcA = TestingTheClass.CalcA(a, b)
a = 2
b = 0.01
NewCalcB = TestingTheClass.CalcB(a, b)
```

That makes it so you only have two variables at a time, and they are only defined for the next function so after the `CalcA()` you can get rid of the values in the variable to do `CalcB()`'s variables.

Comment: Yes this could also help but more the way K. Kirsz was defining. Nevertheless Thanks.